# Cumulative count of occurrences per value in array in Kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm looking to get the count of query param usage from the query string from page views stored in app insights using KQL. My query currently looks like:

```
pageViews
| project parsed=parseurl(url)
| project keys=bag_keys(parsed["Query Parameters"])
```

and the results look like

[image]

with each row looking like

[image]

I'm looking to get the count of each value in the list when it is contained in the `url` in order to anwser the question "How many times does page appear in the querystring". So the results might look like:

Page | From | ...

---

1000 | 67  | ...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try something along the following lines:

```
datatable(url:string)
[
    "https://a.b.c/d?p1=hello&p2=world",
    "https://a.b.c/d?p2=world&p3=foo&p4=bar"
]
| project parsed = parseurl(url)
| project keys = bag_keys(parsed["Query Parameters"])
| mv-expand key = ['keys'] to typeof(string)
| summarize count() by key
```

which returns:

```
| key | count_ |
|-----|--------|
| p1  | 1      |
| p2  | 2      |
| p3  | 1      |
| p4  | 1      |
```

Comment: Thanks, I had a hunch it would be simple